# Fast euclidean distance calculation for real time strategy games

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cython

What is the best way to implement a fast distance calculation?

I am coding a bot for starcraft 2, in which many distances have to be calculated every frame.

Here is the part of the library that is being used and I want to improve:
https://github.com/Dentosal/python-sc2/blob/develop/sc2/position.py

I logged the calculations for a 10 minute game, in average there were this many calls every frame:

```
distance_to 10
distance_to_point2 965
_distance_squared 1775
closest 42
```

Note that `closest` consist of a for loop , I tested how big `n` is and got this distribution for a game:

```
0 < n <= 5 : 21389
5 < n <= 10 :  16426
10 < n <=20 :  28202
20 < n <=605 : 13620
60 < n :  34
len n of 'closest' call: 79671
average n of 'closest' call: 13.815654378632125
min n of 'closest' call: 2
max n of 'closest' call: 128
```

My idea was to use numpy and for the "closest" function a vector solution to calculate all distances at once.

There is also another function I would like to implement which is to calculate the closest distances of all members of one list to all members of another list.

Is numpy the right idea? What functions of numpy do i use? Would Cython be better?

Comment: Have a look at [`scipy.spatial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html), it has both a fast KDTree implementation, [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree) for quick nearest neighbor queries as well as a fast implementation of the euclidean distance in [`scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean)

Answer (score 2):

numpy and scipy do all of these kinds of calculations in C. No need to do the cython yourself.

```
%%timeit
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
import numpy as np
matrices = []
for i in range(10):
    matrices.append(np.random.randint(10,size=(1,5)))
[[euclidean(matrices[i],matrix) for i, j in enumerate(matrices)] for matrix in matrices]
```

Comment: For pairwise distances, `scipy.spatial.pdist(points, 'euclidean')` should be used.

Comment: Pretty sure pdist requires dimensionality reduction which means normalization. True much faster for pairwise but not necessarily when you include everything else in the pipeline